# React-Native white area in inspect elements

Tags: react-native, inspect

[react-native inspect elements (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvpnR.png)

Hi guys,
anyone can explain to me, what is the white area between green(padding) and blue(content) area?
how can i remove that?

Comment: You can remove it with CSS. Could you share your React-Native component and CSS?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.